# Debugging on Graphics Timeout (0x887A0006 DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_HUNG)

Tags: debugging, graphics, timeout, gpu, hlsl

I am working on a Direct3D pixel shader, which currently seems to have some infinite loop problem. This causes the graphics device to timeout on the first frame, so that I have no chance of capturing a frame in the [Visual Studio Graphics Diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/graphics/visual-studio-graphics-diagnostics?view=vs-2017) - which can only debug a frame after it has been executed. I also tried the [GPU PerfStudio](https://gpuopen.com/archive/gpu-perfstudio/shader-debugger/), which crashes fatally.

Is there any tool that would let me debug a shader step-by-step?

Comment: Switch from hardware GPU to D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_WARP device? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/d3dcommon/ne-d3dcommon-d3d_driver_type

Comment: @Soonts: How would that help?

Comment: WARP devices are software, they don’t use GPU hardware. Debugging will probably be easier, you won’t have to deal with Windows kernel, dxgikrnl.sys and it’s timeouts.

Comment: @Soonts: Are you able to analyse the operation of the the shader when it's running on the WARP driver?